# c# - using LoadLibrary returns 0 with Win32Error 193

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-c++, dll

I'm building a c# class library that calls third party DLLs supplied by a vendor we're working with. The vendors examples are all in vc++ and are running and working.

I'm trying to load one of the DLLs and it's returning an `IntPtr` 0. When I call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` I get 193 which from what I've read means that I'm trying to load a 32-bit DLL in 64-bit app. But I checked again and again and both my class library is set to `x86` and my console application that makes the call to that class library is set to `x86`.

I can successfully load other DLL files by the same vendor (which are also 32-bit).

This is my Native helper class:

```
class NativeHelper
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadLibrary", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadLibraryEx", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryEx(string dllToLoad, IntPtr hFile, LoadLibraryFlags flags);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    [System.Flags]
    public enum LoadLibraryFlags : uint
    {
        DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES = 0x00000001,
        LOAD_IGNORE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL = 0x00000010,
        LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE = 0x00000002,
        LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE = 0x00000040,
        LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE = 0x00000020,
        LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH = 0x00000008,
        LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR = 0x00000100,
        LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32 = 0x00000800,
        LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS = 0x00001000
    }
}
```

And this is how I make the call:

```
IntPtr pDll = NativeHelper.LoadLibrary(@"dhplay.dll"); // returns 0
if (pDll == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    var err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString(); // returns 193
    Console.WriteLine(err);
}
```

What am I missing here? If I'm running `x86` why is that DLL not loaded and others do?

**Edit** (Additional information):

`IntPtr.Size` is 4

`dumpbin` returns `8664 machine (x64)` - That means it's 64-bit? I checked for other DLL used and they are `8664 machine (x86)`

As far as dependencies, it's working on a vc++ application on my machine.

Comment: Just to be sure, try printing `IntPtr.Size`...

Comment: Then use `dumpbin` (you should have it in path if you use the Visual Studio command prompt): `dumpbin /headers yourdll.dll | more`. One of the first rows should be `machine (x86/x64)`

Comment: Another possibility: you have some missing dependancies on the dll... Use http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to see what other dlls your dll uses and check if they are installed. Perhaps your dll is using a specific version of the MSVCRT that you don't have on your PC.

Comment: Yes it means It is 64bits

Comment: So apprantly I have 64 and 32 bit dlls - can they be run in the same application? because it seems that that's what the vc++ does

Comment: No they can't. What dll is VC++ running at 32 + 64 bits? Note that system dll (kernel32, user32 and similar) are both 32 and 64 bits.

Comment: Are you sure that ANY CPU is not set?

Answer (score 0):

If there is smoke, there is often fire. Some dll is probably x64 while your app is x32 (or the reverse).

- Check in you app `IntPtr.Size`. 4 → x86, 32 bits, 8 → x64, 64 bits
- If you use the Visual Studio Command Prompt, you should be able to use `dumpbin`. Do a `dumpbin /headers yourdll.dll | more` for your dlls. One of the first rows should be `machine (...)`. In the `(...)` it should be written if it is x86 (so 32 bits) or x64 (so 64 bits)

To the second question, you can't in any way mix 32 and 64 bit dlls in a single process. Some programs "cheat" and create a secondary process with the correct bits to load the dlls and then do IPC (inter-process-communication) between the primary process and the secondary process to use the dll. Clearly it is complex.